# Microsoft Excel VBA Scripting: Recursive column matching

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

```
Sub NewMacro()
Dim endRow As Long
endRow = Sheet1.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To endRow
 If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = Sheet1.Range("F" & i).Value Then
    Sheet1.Range("K" & i).Value = "Yes"     Else
    Sheet1.Range("K" & i).Value = "No"
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This will compare column A with column F and displays the result in column K.
What I need is if this value is true, then like the above it should compare column B with column G, column C with column H and so on......and should display the results in next column. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a loop on the columns:

```
Sub NewMacro()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    With Sheet1
        endRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To endRow
            For c = 1 To 5
                If .Cells(i, c).Value = .Cells(i, c + 5).Value Then
                    .Cells(i, c + 10).Value = "Yes"
                Else
                    .Cells(i, c + 10).Value = "No"
                End If
            Next c
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

This compares column A with F, column B with G, column C with H, column D with I and column E with J.  Results are placed in columns K, L, M, N and O respectively.

This is equivalent to using the formula `=IF(A1=F1,"Yes","No")` in cell K1 and copying it across and down.

---

And a version which will update columns with "Yes", but stop as soon as it reaches a "No":

```
Sub NewMacro()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    With Sheet1
        endRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To endRow
            For c = 1 To 5
                If .Cells(i, c).Value = .Cells(i, c + 5).Value Then
                    .Cells(i, c + 10).Value = "Yes"
                Else
                    .Cells(i, c + 10).Value = "No"
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next c
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. :)

Comment: First code is ok, however, only if result in column K is "Yes" then match column B with G and so on. If K="No" then no further matching on that row.

Comment: @TitusSam I have updated the answer with a version that keeps inserting "Yes" values, but stops as soon as it hits a "No".